# Setup Windows update downloads in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, download, automatic-update

When checking for Windows Updates, most of time there are more than one available and in that case each update is downloaded in turn. When one download completes, another starts automatically.

1. In the case of more than one update, how would I download only a specific update?
2. Can I stop an update in the middle of it being downloaded?
3. Can I interrupt and postpone an update that has already started installing?

Comment: You interrupt a Windows Update by disconnecting from the internet.  What exactly are you trying to do by downloading only a single update?  That typically would require WSUS which allows for more fine control of which updates are installed. “When another completes” - this typically only happens on a machine that hasn’t been updated and requires specific updates in order to continue to receive updates through Windows Update

Comment: @Ramhound when checking for Windows Updates, it detects various types of updates. Once updates detected, I want to download and install specific update(s) not all. Second, if any update starts download, how to stop its download. And sometime, I just want to download and want to install later.

Comment: Windows Update on Windows 10 doesn’t work like that, if you want that amount of control, use WSUS and distribute only the updates you want to your machine.  You won’t be able to do it otherwise, Windows Updates are required on Windows 10, the only updates you have any control over, are the optional updates

Answer (score 2):

(1) If Windows Updates is showing you more than one update (occurs for different Windows items like Defender and Feature for example - different) you can select which ones you wish to do now and which later.

Unless you are on a business LTS or other business license, you do have to do all updates at some point.

(2) If you have downloaded some updates and stop the process (however you stop the download), what you have downloaded will update. The partial download will restart downloading at a later time.

(3) Once a download is complete and Windows wishes to install, you can postpone installation at that point for a number of days.

If installation has occurred, you must restart, but even that can be postponed to a later time or the overnight restart time

It is generally better to allow updates to download and not interrupt them.

You can organize update and install time with Windows 10 Update scheduling. There is now (for quite a while) no need to have restarts interrupt your work.

Good luck with scheduling.